# "DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint EF core" after SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core with .net core 2.2 and am encountering a strange intermittent issue.

In my case I have these three tables with entities (simplified):
Data Model:

```
public class Case : BaseEntity
    {
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
        public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    }
    public class Client : BaseEntity
    {
        public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
        public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Case> Case { get; set; }
    }
```

Configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Case>(entity =>
            { entity.HasOne(d => d.Client).WithMany(p => p.Case).HasForeignKey(d => d.ClientId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
});
```

In order to add a new Case in code I am doing something like this:

```
1. Begin the transaction

2. Calling a SP in which I am adding a client and adding some dependenttable info and returning the ClientId from  it.

3. I am passing the client Id to next step as mentioned below:

objCase.Client=objClient;
objCase.ClientId=objClient,ClientId;
_Context.Client.Add(objCase);

4. Now I am calling the below methods which is throwing the exception
_context.SaveChanges();
```

So far this has worked fine and a new entry is created in the Client table with the ID and personId and a new entry is created in the Case table with an entry linking the Client to the establishment.

Suddenly I am encountering an error for one user (but not another) where the code hangs for a while and then gives the following exception:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Case_Client_ClientId". The conflict occurred in database "CenterManagementSystem", table "dbo.Case", column 'ClientId'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Full AppInsight:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2019-06-11T10:30:42.1388220Z","sampleRate":50,"tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"ICEN083","ai.operation.id":"e18f8d7fa6aecf448350d74dea9ceedb","ai.operation.parentId":"|e18f8d7fa6aecf448350d74dea9ceedb.65995757_","ai.operation.name":"POST Clients/PostCase [clientId/orgId]","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rdddsc:2.9.1-26132","ai.internal.nodeName":"ICEN083"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"servername | CenterManagementSystem","id":"0602a78dd80f4716a98e37f9fa8c9c91","data":"SET NOCOUNT ON;\r\nDELETE FROM [Client]\r\nWHERE [ClientId] = @p0;\r\nSELECT @@ROWCOUNT;","duration":"00:00:02.5031198","resultCode":"547","success":false,"type":"SQL","target":"servername | CenterManagementSystem","properties":{"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"qa","DeveloperMode":"true","_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.1')","Exception":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_Case_Client_ClientId\". The conflict occurred in database \"CenterManagementSystem\", table \"dbo.Case\", column 'ClientId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)\r\nClientConnectionId:58a6c6e2-b1a8-41ea-93a3-f8fbce2035d3\r\nError Number:547,State:0,Class:16"}}}}
```

I guess my main question is why is entity framework trying to delete something in the process of doing an insert?

Any insight, help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This Code working with .Net Core 2.1. But after upgradation with 2.2 cause this issue. Really need  help for it. Thnks

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? How did you register `_Context`? Are there many users handle the same record?

Comment: @TaoZhou : Thanks for your quick reply. I have created _Context object perfectly in code, its working for the other DB entities. Right there is no demo for it. I have maintaining the solution in my PC.

Comment: For your current code, it is saving operation, but it throws delete exception. It is difficult to analyse your issue without reproducing it.

Comment: Are you modifying the client id somewhere? That would cause your foreign key to be 'deleted'.